# Validation both client and server side JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, validation, jax-ws, client-side, server-side

I made a simple webservice with JAXWS, the server contains my beans annotated with validation contraints and web methods which are inserting or updating beans in database.

I create my beans with forms on the client-side and then call the web methods to save changes.
For the moment I validate my bean with hibernate validator, on the server-side, inside web methods.
I would like to make dynamic form validation on the client side. But with the wsdl generation, my beans have no more annotations, so nothing is validated.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the client side schema validation [as mentioned here](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Schema_Validation.html#Client_Side_Schema_Validation)